# Remove elements before they are added to the DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

A series of `.cell` elements are created on `document` load.
They are only useful if also an **`img`** is added within them.
I need to keep them from being created because they are linked to the creation of other `li` elements.

Thank you.

Source Code:

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="parent-container">

       <div class="cell">     !always added
          <div class="container">     !always added
             <div class="screen"></div>     !always added
             <img> **!If added**
          </div>                                            
       </div>

  </div>
  <li>Created even if not needed</li>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your jQuery code, where you create these elements.

Comment: This is not well explained and it is unclear what you want. Also where's this mysterious document load code?

Comment: You can display:none those elements and decide when they appears by jquery (calling the class and setting display:block) or not render them in the html, and render them by jquery (when you want it)

Comment: I have ten divs of this kind in the source code, but I only need the document to load some of them in different instances. Sometimes 10, sometimes 3 and sometimes 5, depending on the images added to a Wordpress post. The image is added dinamycally if there is any. Not really a jQuery doing this.

Comment: What do you mean with "Not really a jQuery doing this"? You can choose what divs will be loaded by Jquery...

Comment: if image node exist then  you dnt want to remove them from DOM ?

Comment: Exactly.   (Its a php (retrieves the image if any)). So if theres no <img> the ´.cell´ should be removed before it is loaded, so that a corresponding ´li´ is not created. Exactly.   (Its a php (retrieves the image if any)). So if theres no <img> , the ´.cell´ should be removed before it is loaded, so that a corresponding ´li´ is not created. I can remove it after it is created but thats not enough to keep the ´li´from showing up.

Answer (score 1):

[.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) the set of matched elements from the DOM.

> Similar to .empty(), the .remove() method takes elements out of the
>   DOM. Use .remove() when you want to remove the element itself, as well
>   as everything inside it. In addition to the elements themselves, all
>   bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed.
>   To remove the elements without removing data and events, use .detach()
>   instead.

Simple Example :html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello">Hello</div>
  <div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
 $( ".hello" ).remove();
```

Solution For you :-

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       var img=$('.cell>div>div img');
        if(img.length>0){
          return;
        } else 
        {
          $('.cell').remove();
    }
});
```

run this code in document ready scope you will get the result .

Answer (score 0):

Next code, check your page before render it.
`<li>` is defined for not being showed at the beggining. After check whatever you want to check you decide if it showed or not...

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    if (your_condition) {
        $("#li_1").show();
    } else {

    }
});

<li id="li_1" style="display:none"><!--DO YOUR STUFF--></li>
```